# How to remove a hash item under some condition

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a hash like this.

```
h = {1 => 2, 2 => 3, 5 => 8, 4 => 2, 3 => 3}
```

I want to delete items whose key is bigger than 3 like this:

```
h.each{|k,v| p "delete this" if k > 3}
```

How can I delete an item inside a loop? Or is there better way to delete an item with a condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h.each{|k,_| h.delete(k) if k > 3}
```

or

```
h.delete_if{|k,_| k > 3}
```